# How does Javascript return work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have

```
$wrapper.find('li').sort(function (a, b) {
  return +a.getAttribute('data-val') - +b.getAttribute('data-val');
});
```

It works, as I see in Chrome dev tool an array of objects is indeed returned but...my question is: What's up with that return? How can I use that array?

What I want to do i to take the returned array, and stick it inside a  tag.

Comment: read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: You should be aware that `.sort()` isn't a supported jQuery method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply assign it:

```
yourArray = $wrapper.find('li').sort(function (a, b) {
  return +a.getAttribute('data-val') - +b.getAttribute('data-val');
});
```

You can then use `yourArray`.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't get it! I'm sure I tried something similar but clearly made some mistakes! Thanks a lot!